# second page of pageindexchanging is blank?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, page-index-changed

Just to check, is the below codes correct? `SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataBind()`? It is because my second page was empty when I tried to view them. Or could it because I am binding a gridview inside a gridview? Please tell me if I need to update my code on binding my "inside" grid.

My code:

```
protected void SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataBind();
}
```

Design:

```
<asp:GridView ID="SubmitAppraisalGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" onrowcreated="SubmitAppraisalGrid_RowCreated" ShowHeader="False" style="margin-right: 0px" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="1" OnPageIndexChanging="SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
 <asp:TemplateField>
  <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:Label ID="QuestionLbl" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Question")%>'></asp:Label>
    <br />
    <br />
<asp:GridView ID="StaffAppraisalGrid" runat="server"AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderWidth="0px" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="StaffName" HeaderText="Name">
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Rate">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioList" runat="server" CellPadding="8" 
    DataSource='<%# Bind("RadioButtonList")%>' RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Remarks">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="RemarksTbx" runat="server" CssClass="remarkTbx" 
        MaxLength="500" Text='<%# Bind("RemarkTbx")%>' TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
  </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your markup, you are not using any typed data source. if you are handling datagrid's databind event then put it in the code else add data source on `PageIndexChanging` event also..

```
protected void SubmitAppraisalGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            SubmitAppraisalGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataSource = (SomeDataSource that you are using);
            SubmitAppraisalGrid.DataBind();
        }
```

Refer [GridView.PageIndexChanging Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.pageindexchanging.aspx).

Comment: Hey thanks it works, but can i ask, what if i want to keep the records of the previous index? Because now i databind() it right? Basically now i am having a small grid in a big grid while pageindexchanging is for the big grid.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way:

Inside Gridview index Canging

```
{
    GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Emp_Data ORDER BY [ID] DESC", con);

    SqlDataAdapter DA1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DA1.Fill(DT1);

    GridView1.DataSource = DT1;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

Use same Query which using in Databind